# Periodic MySql timeout followed by connection spike in ASP.NET website

Tags: mysql, asp.net, .net, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Every couple of days we have been getting a small number of MySql timeout errors that correspond with a large spike in CPU and DB connections on our MySQL RDS instance. These are queries that are typically very fast (<5ms) that suddenly timeout.

At this point, database operations are very slow for a minute or so (likely because new connections are being allocated).  The number of new connections often doubles and seem to correspond to the entire Connection Pool being recycled.

The timeouts do not seem to correspond with heavy database load.  The CPU is often under 7% when this happens spiking up to around 12%.

Once these connections are created, the old connections seem to stay around for several hours.

We have some theories:

- An occasional network hiccup between EC2 and RDS
- A connection pool recycle (is there such a thing?)
- Resource contention on the server that backs up all queries (no deadlocks present)

Any help on debugging this would be very much appreciated.

System Details:

- Windows 2012 EC2 instances
- .NET 4.5
- MySql Connector 6.8.3
- Entity Framework 6.0.2
- MySql.Data.Entities 6.8.3
- MySql 5.6.12 (Hosted in Amazon's RDS)

Comment: What does your PROCESS LIST show you when you're having issues?

Comment: It does sounds like connection leak. Do you use readers, connections etc yourself directly without disposing them (wrap such things in using statements)?

Comment: You can try a few things: a) "show innodb status" when this happens looking for locks. b) see your db connection count trend over the two days - is it steadily going up?  c) look at your connection pooling settings in more detail - your max idle time etc.  d) try creating a new ec2 instance and see if the same issue happens there.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to put this as a comment not an answer but "...must have 50 reputation to comment..."

1. Are you maxing out on connections? show variables like 'max_connections'; show process_list; (as root user)
2. How's your disk I/O: iostat -x 5 via command line and pay special attention to queue sizes & service/wait times. If its an issue you can purchase AWS reserved IOPS for better reliability & performance.
3. You can profile it - i like Jet Profiler, simple & low load.